# How to group by multiple columns with complex types in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, grouping

I'm trying to preform a group by to get all of the students, by college, grouped by status. The problem is the database I'm working with has hundreds of fields in the StudentInfo table, which is why I think this is failing.

I'm basically trying to get counts for the students by their statuses, and grouped by the college they are from.

When I execute this query, I get the following exception.

**The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider.**

Now I believe this is because there are way too many fields on the StudentInfo table, but I can't do anything about that in this case. There has to be a way to do what I want.

I need the following fields returned, all of which are counts, except College.

**College | Accepts | Webapps | Ays | Total**

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Here is my model

```
public class EnrollmentCountsBySchool
{
    // selected terms
    public int[] SelectedTerms { get; set; }
    // list of terms
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Terms { get; set; }

    // selected programs
    public int[] SelectedPrograms { get; set; }
    // list of programs
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Programs { get; set; }

    // selected statuses
    public string[] SelectedStatuses { get; set; }
    // list of statuses
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses { get; set; }

    // list of results
    public List<EnrollmentCountsBySchoolResult> Results { get; set; }
```

My Query (way to long, I know.)

```
 var results =
            (from student in db.StudentInfo
             join college in db.Colleges on student.College.Id equals college.Id
             where model.SelectedTerms.Contains(student.TermOfInterestId.Value) &&
                   model.SelectedPrograms.Contains(student.ProgramId.Value) &&
                   model.SelectedStatuses.Contains(student.Status)

             group student by new
             {
                 College = college.Name,
                 Accepts = (
                         from s in db.StudentInfo
                         join c in db.Colleges on student.College.Id equals college.Id
                         where model.SelectedTerms.Contains(student.TermOfInterestId.Value) &&
                               model.SelectedPrograms.Contains(student.ProgramId.Value) &&
                               model.SelectedStatuses.Contains(student.Status) &&
                               student.Status.ToLower().Contains("accepted") ||
                               student.Status.ToLower().Contains("applicant")
                         group s by new
                         {
                             College = c.Name,
                         } into accepts
                         select new
                         {
                             accepts.Key.College,
                             Count = accepts.Count()
                         }
                 ),
                 Webapps =
                 (
                         from s in db.StudentInfo
                         join c in db.Colleges on student.College.Id equals college.Id
                         where model.SelectedTerms.Contains(student.TermOfInterestId.Value) &&
                               model.SelectedPrograms.Contains(student.ProgramId.Value) &&
                               model.SelectedStatuses.Contains(student.Status) &&
                               student.Status.ToLower().Contains("webapp")
                         group s by new
                         {
                             College = c.Name,
                         } into webapps
                         select new
                         {
                             webapps.Key.College,
                             Count = webapps.Count()
                         }
                 ),
                 Ays = (
                         from s in db.StudentInfo
                         join c in db.Colleges on student.College.Id equals college.Id
                         where model.SelectedTerms.Contains(student.TermOfInterestId.Value) &&
                               model.SelectedPrograms.Contains(student.ProgramId.Value) &&
                               model.SelectedStatuses.Contains(student.Status) &&
                               !student.Status.ToLower().Contains("accepted") &&
                               !student.Status.ToLower().Contains("applicant") &&
                               !student.Status.ToLower().Contains("webapp")
                         group s by new
                         {
                             College = c.Name,
                         } into ays
                         select new
                         {
                             ays.Key.College,
                             Count = ays.Count()
                         }
                 ),
                 Total = (
                         from s in db.StudentInfo
                         join c in db.Colleges on student.College.Id equals college.Id
                         where model.SelectedTerms.Contains(student.TermOfInterestId.Value) &&
                               model.SelectedPrograms.Contains(student.ProgramId.Value) &&
                               model.SelectedStatuses.Contains(student.Status)
                         group s by new
                         {
                             College = c.Name,
                         } into totals
                         select new
                         {
                             totals.Key.College,
                             Count = totals.Count()
                         }
                 )

             }
                 into grouping
                 select new EnrollmentCountsBySchoolResult
                 {
                     College = grouping.Key.College,
                     Accepts = grouping.Key.Accepts.Count(),
                     Webapps = grouping.Key.Webapps.Count(),
                     Ays = grouping.Key.Ays.Count(),
                     Total = grouping.Key.Total.Count()
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: This looks like very weird code. If I understand correctly, you are grouping on college and want to output aggregate data for each college. If that is the case, why are the aggregates appearing in the key? The key is what LINQ will attempt to group on.

Comment: I'm trying to get how many students have been accepted, webapps, not accepted or webapps, any status. Then group that by college.

Comment: That's sort of backwards. You are trying to group students by college, then for each college, get various aggregates. The only thing appearing in your group by clause should be college.Name.

The exception, by the way, is telling you that LINQ doesn't know how to convert your group by into SQL, because grouping involves comparing expressions for equality and it doesn't know how to do that for these complex expressions.

In my experience you are much better off writing complex grouping queries as a SQL stored procedure, but perhaps some LINQ guru will drop by and disagree :)

Comment: @CarlWeis did you try LINQPad to see what this LINQ expression evaluates to in SQL?

Comment: Thanks man, I reversed the query and it worked. :)

Comment: @JunaidKirkire No, just reversed the query and it worked. I'm sure it's a mess of T-SQL, but performance isn't a concern right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up re-writing the query to search by colleges and join students, then do the grouping and I got the results I was looking for.

```
       var results =
            from college in db.Colleges
            join student in db.StudentInfo on college.Id equals student.UniversityId
            where model.SelectedTerms.Contains(student.TermOfInterestId.Value) &&
                  model.SelectedPrograms.Contains(student.ProgramId.Value) &&
                  model.SelectedStatuses.Contains(student.Status)
            group college by new
            {
                College = college.Name,
                Accepts = (
                 from c1 in db.Colleges
                 join s1 in db.StudentInfo on c1.Id equals s1.UniversityId
                 where model.SelectedTerms.Contains(s1.TermOfInterestId.Value) &&
                       model.SelectedPrograms.Contains(s1.ProgramId.Value) &&
                       model.SelectedStatuses.Contains(s1.Status) &&
                       s1.UniversityId == college.Id &&
                       s1.Status.ToLower().Contains("accepted") || s1.Status.ToLower().Contains("applicant")
                 select c1
                ).Count(),
                Webapps = (
                    from c2 in db.Colleges
                    join s2 in db.StudentInfo on c2.Id equals s2.UniversityId
                    where model.SelectedTerms.Contains(s2.TermOfInterestId.Value) &&
                          model.SelectedPrograms.Contains(s2.ProgramId.Value) &&
                          model.SelectedStatuses.Contains(s2.Status) &&
                          s2.UniversityId == college.Id &&
                          s2.Status.ToLower().Contains("webapp")
                    select c2
                ).Count(),
                Ays = (
                    from c3 in db.Colleges
                    join s3 in db.StudentInfo on c3.Id equals s3.UniversityId
                    where model.SelectedTerms.Contains(s3.TermOfInterestId.Value) &&
                          model.SelectedPrograms.Contains(s3.ProgramId.Value) &&
                          model.SelectedStatuses.Contains(s3.Status) &&
                          s3.UniversityId == college.Id &&
                          !s3.Status.ToLower().Contains("accepted") && !s3.Status.ToLower().Contains("applicant") &&
                          !s3.Status.ToLower().Contains("webapp")
                    select c3
                ).Count()
            }
                into grouping
                select new EnrollmentCountsBySchoolResult
                {
                    College = grouping.Key.College,
                    Accepts = grouping.Key.Accepts,
                    Webapps = grouping.Key.Webapps,
                    Ays = grouping.Key.Ays,
                    Total = grouping.Count()
                };

        model.Results = results.OrderByDescending(o => o.Total).ToList();
```